# PLOT in Mathematica using NArgMax vs FindArgMax

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Ive been having some trouble using Plot to graph a complicated composite function.

I am trying to plot the `ArgMax` of a composite function `F[]`.

`F[]` involves several levels of nested composite functions, many of which involve `Solve[]` and `Min[]` or `Max[]`.

I don't have any problems with the way `F[]` performs in my program (with the possible exception of how it renders in Plot), so I wont include the lengthy code that defines `F[]` and its underlying simpler functions, for now.

When I try to use

`Plot[FindArgMax[F[],{vars}]`, I get a very fast return on my output, which is mostly correct, except for the fact that I get a range with some buggy false values, which appear to be rendered as incorrect vertical segments over a portion of the plot.

I have evaluated `F[]` over the range where the bugginess is happening, and have confirmed that the proper values are in line with the smooth curve shown in the second pic below.

[image]

`Plot[NArgMax[[F[],{vars}]`, I get a correct plot which does not include the bugginess/false vertical segments, but it takes a considerably longer time.

I cant post a second link, but the `NArgMax` plot generates the same picture as above, but smooth and without the holes and vertical segments.

Without getting into the specifics of `F[]`, is there a quick and easy way to coax `FindArgMax` into working properly here? Basically, is this a common issue with Plot that has a well known fix, or do I need to devote more time to recoding my definitions of `F[]` and the underlying composite functions if I want to be able to use the fast FindArgMax command in my Plot?

Thanks in advance for any help, from a first timer here on the forum. :)

EDIT: Sample code from the troublesome portion of my program:

```
 a = 3000; b = 1/10; cc = 1/10; d = 1;
```

G1[x_, y_] := a Log[b x + cc  y + d]

Gx1[x_, y_] := Derivative[1, 0][G1][x, y];
Gy1[x_, y_] := Derivative[0, 1][G1][x, y];

piPP1 = {y, x};

c1ycrit0[fy_, mu1_] := 
 Max[0, Flatten[
     Solve[Gy1[x, y] == fy mu1 && piPP1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)] == piPP1[[2]], y, 
      x]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]]

c1xcrit1[fx_, fy_, mu1_] := Max[Quiet[
   Flatten[
      Solve[Gx1[x, 
         Flatten[Solve[piPP1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)] == piPP1[[2]], y]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]] == 
        mu1 fx, x]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]], 
  Quiet[Flatten[
      Solve[Gx1[x, 
         Max[0, Flatten[
             Solve[Gy1[x, y] == fy*mu1 && piPP1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)] == piPP1[[2]], y,
               x]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]]] == mu1 fx, x]]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]]

c1xcrit2[fx_, fy_, mu1_, T1_] := 
 Max[Quiet[
   Flatten[Solve[T1 == x fx + fy c1ycrit0[fy, mu1] , x, 
       y]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]], 
  Quiet[Flatten[
      Solve[{piPP1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)] == piPP1[[2]], T1 == x fx + fy piPP1[[2]]}, x,
        y]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUsQ.gif)][[2]]]]

Manipulate[
 Quiet[Plot[(fx - xc) Max[0, 
     Min[c1xcrit1[fx, fy, mu1], c1xcrit2[fx, fy, mu1, T1]]], {fx, 0, 
    fxMax}, PlotRange -> {{0, fxMax}, {0, xPTmax}}]],
 {{mu1, 10, Subscript[Mu, 1]}, 0, 100}, {{xc, 3}, 0, 
  100}, {{fy, 10}, 0, 100}, {{T1, 100}, 0, 1000}, {{fxMax, 50}, 0, 
  100}, {{xPTmax, 100}, 0, 400}, ContinuousAction -> None]

BRX[fy_, xc_, mu1_, T1_] := 
 Quiet[FindArgMax[(fx - 
      xc) (Min[{c1xcrit1[fx, fy, mu1], 
       c1xcrit2[fx, fy, mu1, T1]}]), {fx, xc}]]

BRX1[fy_, xc_, mu1_, T1_] := 
 Quiet[NArgMax[(fx - 
      xc) (Min[{c1xcrit1[fx, fy, mu1], c1xcrit2[fx, fy, mu1, T1]}]), 
   fx]]

Manipulate[
 xBR = Plot[BRX[fy, xc, mu1, T1], {fy, 0, hmax}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, hmax}, {0, hmax}}], {{mu1, 10, 
   Subscript[Mu, 1]}, 0, 100}, {{xc, 3}, 0, 10}, {{T1, 100}, 0, 
  1000}, {{hmax, 40}, 0, 100}, ContinuousAction -> None]

Manipulate[
 xBR1 = Plot[BRX1[fy, xc, mu1, T1], {fy, 0, hmax}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, hmax}, {0, hmax}}], {{mu1, 10, 
   Subscript[Mu, 1]}, 0, 100}, {{xc, 3}, 0, 10}, {{T1, 100}, 0, 
  1000}, {{hmax, 40}, 0, 100}, ContinuousAction -> None]

Further edit: Changing the starting point "xc" for solving for "fx" in the BRX[] function drastically changes the result of the plot, which leads me to believe that it might be unlikely that I will be able to usefully use FindArgMax at all. I suppose that the derivatives are all a little too screwy due to all the MINs and MAXs in the underlying functions. Im still hopeful that there is a fix here that will enable to use FindArgMax, but Im a lot less optimistic after trying a few of the things suggested so far.

Thanks again to everyone for your help so far! :)

Comment: There's nothing definite I can say without looking at `F[]`. Have you tried changing the `WorkingPrecision` and/or `Method` used in `FindArgMax`? Also examine what's going on with the `StepMonitor` option. It might be that `FindArgMax` takes a particularly large step that takes it out of the range of sensible values that `F[]` likes...

Comment: You need to find out what is happening in the bad results from FindArgMax. First use EvaluationMonitor to find an example abscissa that is going wrong. Then use EvaluationMonitor again in that specific call to FindArgMax to find out what it is getting up to. Then plot F in the regions that FindArgMax ends up looking, and see what is going wrong with it. There are examples in the FindArgMax documentation showing how to plot EvaluationMonitor or StepMonitor results together with the function, to get an idea what the algorithm is finding and doing.

Comment: just a tip, including a self-contained example (in <pre></pre> tags for less than ~30 lines, link to pastebin otherwise) greatly increases your chances of getting a useful answer, even if the example is quite large

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys :) Ive been working a bit more on the program trying to use some of the advice in this thread. In the mean time, I will follow Yaroslav's advice and post an example of the code from one of the troublesome parts of my program. (Im quite the novice when it comes to Mathematica, so I apologize for the extreme inelegance of the code I am about to post).

Comment: KennyTM, thanks for the edit yesterday to add the pic and link. Unfortunately I had to remove those when I edit the original post to add the sample code.

Comment: Sorry, 2 typos in sample code have now been fixed.

Comment: You would benefit from not always using delayed evaluation.  Your expressions for Gx1[] and Gy1[] are immediately evaluable.  Your function c1ycrit0[] is also (c1ycrit0[fy_, mul_] = Max[0, -5*(fy mul - 300)/(fy mul)]) and I assume your other functions collapse similarly.  Since the resulting right-hand sides are so simple, there's no need for delayed evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Relevant answer (see below for original)

Looking at your code, the problem is really about understanding delayed/immediate evaluation in Mathematica. For example, observe how nicely the following renders, compared to your first `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[(fx - xc) Max[0, 
     Min[c1xcrit1[fx, fy, mu1], c1xcrit2[fx, fy, mu1, T1]]]], {fx, 0, 
   fxMax}, PlotRange -> {{0, fxMax}, {0, xPTmax}}], {{mu1, 10, 
   Subscript[Mu, 1]}, 0, 100}, {{xc, 3}, 0, 100}, {{fy, 10}, 0, 
  100}, {{T1, 100}, 0, 1000}, {{fxMax, 50}, 0, 100}, {{xPTmax, 100}, 
  0, 400}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the only difference is an `Evaluate` which evaluates the expression to be plotted once and for all, instead of doing all the symbolical math over each time a new plot is needed. I suspect adding `Evaluate` in a similar way to your other plots would do the trick once you get your errors fixed.

If you want to learn how you should have coded the above, here are some study points:

- Learn about `Rule` (`->`)  and `ReplaceAll` (`./`): Instead of saying `Flatten[{{y->x+2}}[[1]][[2]]`, you should use `y/.First[{{y-> x+2}}]`.
- Drop the `Quiet`'s. All of them. Now! ;) Really -- unless you are completely sure what you are doing, `Quiet` will just be hiding your mistakes from you.
- Learn about `Set` (`=`) vs `SetDelayed` (`:=`). As an example, see below how I would have implemented your `c1xcrit1`: Using `=` instead of `:=` means that all the symbolic math is done *once when x1xcrit1 is defined* rather than every time it is evaluated.

I hope this helps a bit -- but really, if you want to use Mathematica you should find a tutorial or something to teach you the basics.

```
c1xcrit1[fx_, fy_, mu1_] = With[{
   y1 = y /. First@Solve[piPP1[[1]] == piPP1[[2]], y], 
   y2 = y /. First@Solve[Gy1[x, y] == fy*mu1 && piPP1[[1]] == piPP1[[2]], y, x]
   },Max[
     x /. First@Solve[Gx1[x, y1] == mu1 fx, x], 
     x /. First@Solve[Gx1[x, y2] == mu1 fx, x]]]
```

### Original answer

The two functions you are comparing use very different algorithms: `FindArgMax` is a convenience front-end to `FindMaximum`, while `NArgMax` is a front-end to `NMaximize`. Comparing the methods available for the two functions

- `FindMaximum`/`FindArgMax`: ConjugateGradient, PrincipalAxis, LevenbergMarquardt, Newton, and QuasiNewton (all differential methods),
- `NArgMax`/`NMaximize`: NelderMead, DifferentialEvolution, SimulatedAnnealing and RandomSearch (all pointwise methods).

To put it another way: use `FindMaximum` or `FindArgMax` for nice functions, where the derivatives yield useful information. For nasty function, use `NArgMax`/`NMaximize`.

Since `FindArgMax` almost works, I'll assume your function is nice.
For the differential methods the evolution is first done symbolically in an attempt to establish an analytical expression for the gradient. Quoting from the docs: "FindArgMax first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically."

It sounds like your `F` is sufficiently complicated that symbolic evaluation is not going to go anywhere. If this is the case then prevent symbolic evaluation by wrapping. Also, adding a cache at the same time rarely hurts:

```
Fnum[args__/;And@@(NumericQ/@{args})]:=Fnum[args]=F[args]
```

You might think that this will be as slow as the `NArgMax`, but in many cases you will find that the QuasiNewton algorithms are impressively good at building an estimate of the derivatives it needs.

Given that we don't know your `F` this is of course complete guesswork -- but I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Janus, thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I am a little embarrassed to ask this, but could you explain what you mean by "wrapping"?

Comment: @Johnny Dingo: By wrapping I mean that instead of calling `FindArgMax[F...`, you could define `Fnum` as indicated above, and then call `FindArgMax[Fnum...`. This would avoid any symbolic evaluations of `F`.

Comment: D'oh! I understand now. Thanks again for your help here.

Comment: Im getting a blank graph and a message "... is not a real number ..." error message when I try that. Im still checking to see if I have any syntax errors, but I havent found any so far. Will keep at it.

Comment: Not surprisingly, I did find a syntax error. But after fixing it, the output is the same as before the wrapping. Time to just bite the bullet and accept the longer time of using NArgMax?

Comment: I cant thank you enough for your help! Ive realized all along that I have a *lot* to learn about using Mathematica correctly and efficiently :) But your advice in the second response has been exactly what I needed. I will certainly spend a good bit of time learning how to use Rule and Replace, and rewriting my code using them. But for now, simply changing the definition of the "crit" functions from ":=" to "=" has everything running fast, smooth, and (for the first time) *correctly*. Once again, it is impossible to understate how grateful I am for your taking the trouble to help here!

Comment: No worries - glad I could help. And I highly recommend taking some time to learn Mathematica -- it can be quite mind-altering if you come from a procedural background :)